# Bitmap.Tag is not serialized when using with WCF

Tags: wcf, bitmap

On the server side, i assign Bitmap.Tag = "a string", but  on client side, i always get the Tag == null. 
Where am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag is not marked by [DataMember] attribute, thus it's not serialized